# Makefile compliation issue cannot find *.o no such file or directory

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm trying to make a simple Makefile with files in different subfolders. This is my Makefile

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
IFLAGS = -Iinclude
OPATH = obj/
CPATH = src/

vpath %.h include
vpath %.c src
vpath %.o obj
vpath main bin



main: main.o grille.o io.o jeu.o
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o main $(OPATH)main.o $(OPATH)grille.o $(OPATH)io.o $(OPATH)jeu.o 
    mv $@ bin/
main.o: main.c grille.h io.h jeu.h
    


grille.o : grille.c grille.h
    

io.o: io.c io.h
    

jeu.o: jeu.c jeu.h
    

%.o : 
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $< $(IFLAGS)
    mv $@ $(OPATH)

clean:
    rm obj/* bin/*
```

I have the files in subfolders called src, obj, and include.
I get this error

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find obj/main.o: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find obj/grille.o: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find obj/io.o: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find obj/jeu.o: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:15: main] Error 1
```

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trSB6.png)

Any Ideas how to fix this?

Comment: If you write a target named `foo.o`, make expects you to build a file named `foo.o`.  If you don't build that file, but instead build some other file like `obj/foo.o`, then make cannot work properly.  If you want to build `obj/foo.o` then you should use `obj/foo.o` as the name of your target.  Then it will work.  For a compiler, if you add the options `-o $@` it will always be right (because make sets the variable `$@` to the name of the file it expects your recipe to build.

Comment: @MadScientist I'm very new to makefiles so I'm sorry if there;s something straight forward that I'm supposed to do but I did add obj/ begore my grille.o io.o and jeu.o but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing output files to a different directory than the input files requires extra setup.  You should look at your compile line that make runs.  Does it put the object file in the right place?  If not then that explains why you get those link errors: the object files don't exist where you told the linker they will be, so it fails.

This rule is not right:

```
%.o : 
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $< $(IFLAGS)
        mv $@ $(OPATH)
```

Also, you cannot use vpath to search for targets that are built by makefiles.  That can't work.  vpath can ONLY be used to search for source files (like `.c` or `.h` files).  So these lines don't do anything and should be removed:

```
vpath %.o obj
vpath main bin
```

And these rules are not right: you need to put the object directory here:

```
grille.o : grille.c grille.h
io.o: io.c io.h
jeu.o: jeu.c jeu.h
```

You want something like this:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
IFLAGS = -Iinclude
OPATH = obj/

vpath %.h include
vpath %.c src

bin/main: obj/main.o obj/grille.o obj/io.o obj/jeu.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

main.o: main.c grille.h io.h jeu.h
grille.o : grille.c grille.h
io.o: io.c io.h
jeu.o: jeu.c jeu.h

$(OPATH)%.o : %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```